# What is the best way to chain async actions with sync callback and pass the data?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am using thunk and chaining async action as below.. Everything is working as expected.

```
function dispatchInitialCall(req, q) {
    return dispatch => Promise.all([
        dispatch(validateUser(req))
    ].map(function (promise) {
        return Promise.resolve(promise).reflect();
    })).then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            if(result.isFulfilled()){
            } else {
            }
        });
    });
}

function dispatchParallelCalls(req, q, params) {
    return dispatch =>
        Promise.all([
            dispatch(loadResults(req, q, params)),
            dispatch(loadInitialPromo(req, q))
            ].map(function (promise) {
            return Promise.resolve(promise).reflect();
        })).then(results => {
            results.forEach(result => {
                if(result.isFulfilled()){
                } else {
                }
            });
        });
}


function combineCalls(req, q, params) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(dispatchInitialCall(req, q)).then(() => {
            return dispatch(dispatchParallelCalls(req, q, params))
        })
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to use the response from validateUser directly in dispatchParallelCalls without setting the value in reducer.

I will change the validateUser to accept a callback and so instead of dispatch(dispatchInitialCall(req, q)), Is it possible to get the value of validateUser(req,callback) and directly use the return value here?

Something like ...

```
function combineCalls(req, q, params) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        validateUser(req, function(data){
            params.newProperty=data;
            return dispatch(dispatchParallelCalls(req, q, params))
        })
    }
}
```